# Convert yyyymmdd chararray to yyyy/mm/dd date format

Tags: apache-pig

I want to do a filter between the DAT_015_X column and a fixed date '01/01/2019'

I have loaded the DAT_015_X as a **chararray** column
Then

```
Data_2 = FOREACH Data GENERATE 
   ToString(DAT_015_X,'yyyy/MM/dd) AS mydate;
```

Then

```
Data_3 = FILTER Data_2  BY ((ToDate(mydate,'yyyy/MM/dd) > ToDate('01/01/2019','yyyy/MM/dd));
```

My Origin Data look like :

```
99991231
20200605
20190605
20200605
```

And this a part of the global data

```
MGM_COMPTEUR;CIA_CD_CRV_CIA;CIA_DA_EM_CRV;CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE;CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ;CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ;CIA_VLR_REF_CRV;CIA_NO_SEQ_CRV;CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG;CIA_HEU_CIA;CIA_TM_STP_CRE;CIA_CD_SI;CIA_VLR_1;CIA_DA_ARR_FIC;CIA_TY_ENR;CIA_CD_BTE;CIA_CD_PER;CIA_CD_EFS;CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV;CIA_CD_EVE_CPR;CIA_CD_APLI_TDU;CIA_CD_STE_RTG;CIA_DA_TT_RTG;CIA_NO_ENR_RTG;CIA_DA_VAL_EVE;PSE_001;STR_002;STR_003;CPR_006_VLR;CPR_006_DCM;CPR_006_DVS;CPR_008_VLR;CPR_008_DCM;CPR_008_DVS;CPR_009_VLR;CPR_009_DCM;CPR_009_DVS;CPR_059_VLR;CPR_059_DCM;CPR_059_DVS;CPR_060_VLR;CPR_060_DCM;CPR_060_DVS;RUB_205;RUB_216;DAT_015_X;NB_005_VLR;NB_005_DCM;NB_007_VLR;NB_007_DCM;NB_012_VLR;NB_012_DCM;EUR_061_VLR;EUR_061_DCM;EUR_061_CD_DVS;EUR_062_VLR;EUR_062_DCM;EUR_062_CD_DVS
00000000000000000000;22002;20190731;9;9;                                  ;22002                   0000000001;0000000001;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;      ;2019-07-31-18.03.27.880010;002;00000000000000000001;20190731; ;2200;M;02;V;00001;    ; ;ZZZZZZZZ;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;20081112;50421451;065000;060100;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;3   ;40  ;99991231;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;
00000000000000000001;22002;20190731;9;9;                                  ;22002                   0000000002;0000000002;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;      ;2019-07-31-18.03.27.880010;002;00000000000000000001;20190731; ;2200;M;02;V;00001;    ; ;ZZZZZZZZ;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;20081112;52289527;065000;060100;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000003000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;1   ;40  ;20200605;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000003000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;
00000000000000000002;22002;20190731;9;9;                                  ;22002                   0000000003;0000000003;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;      ;2019-07-31-18.03.27.880010;002;00000000000000000001;20190731; ;2200;M;02;V;00001;    ; ;ZZZZZZZZ;ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ;20081112;52439938;065000;060100;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000001000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;1   ;40  ;20190605;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000000000000;00;+00000000001000000;02;EUR ;+00000000000000000;02;EUR ;
```

But this return this message error

> Could not infer the matching function for
>   org.apache.pig.builtin.ToString as multiple or none of them fit.
>   Please use an explicit cast.

How can I resolve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for that issue is very simple.

In fact I declared the variable  **DAT_015_X**  as long data instead of chararray.
Then, I create the filter as :

```
Data_2 = FILTER Data  BY (DAT_015_X > 20190101);
```

And it gives the needed result.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are missing end quote i.e. ' in the format 'yyyy/MM/dd.
Assuming your DAT_015_X is in `yyyyMMdd` format use this

```
Data_2 = FILTER Data  BY ((ToDate(DAT_015_X,'yyyyMMdd') > ToDate('20190101','yyyyMMdd'));
```

Comment: @VK_2017 thank you for your respons. In real my DAT_015_X is in yyyyMMdd format But I tried to make it in yyyyMMdd format. Is it possible to convert it directly to yyyy/MM/dd using ToDate even it's in yyyyMMdd format in reality ?

Comment: No, ToDate is used to convert your existing chararray datetime to datetime.So in this case since your chararray format is yyyyMMdd, you need to specify that as the format for ToDate.I've edited the answer.Try it.

Comment: this returns to me failed to read data from and failed to produce result in

Comment: it returns `ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: CRE_22002_DATA: New For Each(false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,fa` and `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "DAT_015_X"`

Comment: I think it can't know DAT_015_X that is a date variable when the format is yyyyMMdd

Comment: Please post sample data from the file.Bottom line is you need to use the format of that field in ToDate to convert it from chararray to a datetime object

Comment: The format should work if DAT_015_X indeed contains dates.

Comment: look what it returns `Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.TRIM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.`